# Is there still a way to set a Azure role to full trust or is it always the default now?

Tags: azure

I saw links showing a checkbox for full trust but this does not seem to appear when I check the role properties.

[`http://mvwood.com/blog/windows-azure-diagnostics-and-trust-levels/`](http://mvwood.com/blog/windows-azure-diagnostics-and-trust-levels/)

There's also a link here:

[`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369931.aspx#TrustLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369931.aspx#TrustLevel)

But the link does not appear valid any more.

Finally I read that enableNativeCodeExecution should be set like this for full trust.

```
<WebRole name="MockingService" vmsize="Small" enableNativeCodeExecution="false">
```

Can someone explain? Is this now the default and is there no longer a requirement to set the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Full trust is now on by default and according to the docs this attribute is optional.  Check out the MSDN documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557553.aspx#WebRole.

> enableNativeCodeExecution- Optional. The default value is true; native code execution and full
>   trust are enabled by default. Set this attribute to false to disable
>   native code execution for the web role, and use Windows Azure partial
>   trust instead.

Comment: Thanks - I guess someone at MSOFT needs to update the docs. The link I gave was from a Feb 14th Document and it still mentions something about "setting trust level".